# Is there a command that will list all files I modified this year?

Tags: command-line

I want to list all the files I've modified this year and back those up. Does anyone know if there is a command to list them?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know that that in concept is the best idea.  Modified will find a ton of files on your system that you would need to omit.  Are you trying this on a user home directory?  Or the entire system?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to find files, the `find` command is a powerful tool. You can look through a directory and print out the paths of all files that match some tests:

```
# find all files in /some/directory whose name starts with 'project_b'
find /some/directory -iname 'project_b*'

# find all files in /some/directory which are owned by user 'joe'
find /some/directory -user joe

# find all files in /some/directory whose name starts with 'project_b'
# but which are *not* owned by user 'joe'
find /some/directory -iname 'project_b*' -and -not -user joe
```

To get the date of the last modification of a file (or more precise, the last modification of a file's content), you can check for the mtime timestamp. `find` has a test for mtime:

```
# find all files, whose mtime is less than 365 days back
find /some/directory -mtime -365
```

That so far gives you a list of all files you want to backup. Now for the backup itself. `find` brings an option called `-exec` that applies a command to every file it finds:

```
find /some/directory -iname '*.txt' -exec cp {} /somewhere/else \;
```

If the find command finds `test.txt`, `other.txt` and `something.txt`, the `-exec` part would execute:

```
cp test.txt /somewhere/else
cp other.txt /somehwere/else
cp something.txt /somewhere/else
```

As you probably can see, the `{}` is replaced with the file in question.

EDIT: You probably need to find a better solution than just `cp` for the backup itself, because `cp` would just copy every file to `/somewhere/else` without keeping the directory structure.

Overall, a dedicated backup program might be a better choice.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you very much and take care.

Comment: For such task, it's a good idea to use `--parents` flag with `cp` command, as it preserves the file hierarchy structure and backups those files sharing the same name.

Comment: @Tianren  Thanks for the help!  I appreciate the extra info. Take care.

Comment: If you want to maintain the directory structure of whatever `find`… um… finds you should probably use something like `find ... -print0 | cpio -p0dv /destination`. `cp` doesn't maintain the directory structure (unless the source object is a directory). Also, the `cp` variant could be written better as `-exec cp -t /somewhere/else {} +` which doesn't create a new process for every match.

Comment: @DavidFoerster But isn't the directory structure implicitely maintained, because `find` delivers the relative path (and not just the filename) to `cp`?

Comment: Yes, `find` hands the full source path to `cp`, but no `cp <SRC>... <DEST>` or `cp -t <DST> <SRC>...` will copy all source objects to *exactly* the destination without creating sub-directories, e. g. `cp -t baz foo/a/b bar/c/d` will result in the files `baz/b` and `baz/d`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. To quote a little worn-out phrase, you really learn something new every day.

Comment: You could also redirect the output of `find` to a file, then tell `tar` or `rsync` to use that file as the list of source files

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to keep the date confined to the current year you could use `-newermt` with the date.

This will look in the current directory for any files after November 1st, 2016 and copy them to /target while maintaining directory structure.

```
find . -newermt "2016-11-01 00:00:00" -exec cp --parents {} /target \;
```

The `--parents` added to the cp command allows you to copy the files maintaing the folders it exists within.

For example...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ls
percona-release_0.1-4.xenial_all.deb  t  t2  testdir  testfile2.vm  testfile.vm
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ cp --parents t/output.txt testdir/
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ls testdir/
directory2  t
```

When I copied `t/output.txt` to `testdir/` it created the folder `t` within `testdir/` and then copied the file.

Comment: Just to clarify, what does the  "--parents"  do?  And thank you for both of your responses.

Comment: updated, @Peacemaker5

Comment: What will happen if you enter the command without the  "--parents"?  Thanks again.

Comment: It will copy the entire list of files into /target without creating subfolders

Comment: Thank you for the helpful replies!  I appreciate the info. [Though being a newbie, I don't understand some of it. :-) ]

Answer (score 2):

To list all the files modified this year along with its details:

```
find / -mtime -365 -ls
```

This will list everything from last 365days.

To show only regular files add `-type f` to the above command.

To get a list of all the modified files(with full path):

```
find / -mtime -365
```

You may back-up these files anywhere using `cp` or `scp` etc.

Add `-printf "%f\n"` to end of the command to print only filenames.

Comment: "and back those up"

Comment: Just to clarify, what are "regular files"?  (And thank you for your quick response.)

Comment: @Peacemaker5  I meant non-directory files..

Comment: @Rinzwind just copy the files to where ever...

Comment: Quick question:  How does the "-ls" [list] modify or add to the "find" command?Thanks again.

Comment: It makes the output for each file long (with a lot of information similar but not the same as 'ls -l') - test it and see what it looks like in a wide terminal window (more than 80 characters wide, for example full screen).

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you very much for your replies, and take care.

Comment: Good luck with your backup :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use some aliases

```
alias last-24-hours='sudo find * -ctime -1 -type f'
alias last-week='sudo find * -ctime -7 -type f'
```

and you can make an alias

```
alias last-year='sudo find * -ctime -365 -type f'
```

but it will probably produce a very long list.

-o-

If you want a graphical overview, you can use **baobab**, to see where there is a lot of data (and where you could 'house-clean' before the backup).

-o-

An alternative is to use a tool, that can make an incremental backup, for example ***rsync***. It will automatically find what needs to be added or replaced in the backup.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you very much for both your replies, and take care.